# Can not find boost using AX_BOOST_BASE on Debian

Tags: c++, linux, boost, build, debian

I installed `libboost1.54-dev` and `libboost-filesystem1.54-dev` on Debian testing and try to run `./configure` to find the library to link with. I used `AX_BOOST_BASE[1.53]` in `configure.ac` file and boost libraries are installed in

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_*
libboost_filesystem.a          libboost_filesystem.so         libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0
....
```

When I run `./configure`, the outputs

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.53... yes
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
configure: error: Could not find a version of the library!
```

The output in `config.log`

```
configure:17360: checking for boostlib >= 1.53
configure:17431: g++ -c -g -O2  -I/usr/include conftest.cpp >&5
configure:17431: $? = 0
configure:17433: result: yes
configure:17614: checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available
configure:17638: g++ -c -g -O2  -I/usr/include conftest.cpp >&5
configure:17638: $? = 0
configure:17652: result: yes
configure:17806: error: Could not find a version of the library!
```

At the last, `ldconfig` looks good.

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

How could I run `./configure` successfully without using `./configure --with-boost-lib=<PATH>`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a bug somewhere (autoconf?) and until it fixed there are two options:

Either add `--with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)` to "debian/rules" as described in [wiki.debian.org/qa.debian.org/FTBFS](https://wiki.debian.org/qa.debian.org/FTBFS#A2013-10-27_checking_whether_the_Boost%3a%3aFoo_library_is_available..._yes_configure%3a_error%3a_Could_not_link_against__.21) (for [Debian](http://debian.org) packages)

or to pass `--with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)` to `configure` (manually).

See also [dpkg-architecture(1)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-architecture&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en).

Note: FTBFS stands for "Fails To Build From Source".